# Can I access functions variables?

Tags: javascript, variables

On clicking button I want some function to have its variables defined, is that possible?

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
   x.name = "john";
   x.lastname = "doe";
});

function x(){
   name = "";
   lastname = "";
}
```

How to make function x return name and lastname defined in event listener?

Comment: When is `x()` called?

Comment: I think you are confused by a few things here.  Hopefully this helps: 1. You have to define `x` with `var`, `let`, or `const` before you can go assigning properties to it.  You also need to define your `button` element before you call a click handler.  And your function `x` does nothing at all atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *On clicking button I want some function to have its variables defined, is that possible?*

How functions work is that you define parameters for the function, and then populate the values of those parameters with arguments to the function. This effectively creates variables in the scope of the function with the values of the arguments you provided.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
   x("john", "doe");
});

function x(name="", lastname=""){
  console.log(name, lastname);
}
```

Here I also added default values for the parameters to equal an emtpy string, just in case not enough arguments were sent.

---

> *How to make function `x` return `name` and `lastname` defined in event listener?*

Your use of the word *"return"* is confusing, since functions can return values, but you seem to actually want to assign the values to the variables.

In case you did want to return the same values back, you'd use a `return` statement with an object to deliver the same values back, but I don't think that's what you were after.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `x` within `click` handler to set default parameters for the function. Note, `"name"` is a property of `window`, adjusted identifier to `_name`

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {

  x = function x(_name = "john", lastname = "doe") {
    console.log(_name, lastname)
  }
  
  x()
});

function x(_name, lastname) {
  console.log(_name, lastname)
}
```

```html
<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing something like this means that the anonymous function will be called on click events

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
   x.name = "john";
   x.lastname = "doe";
});
```

it's the same as writing

```
function onClickListener(){
   x.name = "john";
   x.lastname = "doe";
}

button.addEventListener("click", onClickListener);
```

but nothing will be reading the response from the onClickListener function, so no you can not return from the function. You can do this instead

```
var x = {};
function onClickListener(){
   x.name = "john";
   x.lastname = "doe";
}
button.addEventListener("click", onClickListener);
```

This is ugly code using globals but it should work. Once the cick event is calld the global **x** var will have the new values